# I am not sure on how I use Perlbrew with Catalyst

Tags: perl, catalyst, perlbrew

I am trying to use Perlbrew with Catalyst in a brand new server. Perlbrew is already installed and working with the last Perl. The advantages are promising, but I am not sure about my working method.

**When developing**, I usually start a shell whith the user I use for developing, and I start the Catalyst server with the debugger (script/myapp_server.pl).

So, if I use Perlbrew, I must init Perbrew, switch to the required version of Perl, and then run the Catalyst server.

If I close the shell, next time I connect using my developing user, I must switch Perl again to the right version. Everytime, by my error-prone human hand, isn't it?

The production enviroment is in the same machine.

So, **in the production enviroment**, that I use in a shell connected as Root, before I start the Catalyst socket, I must be sure that the right Perl is activated, also by human action.

**And all the modules** that I add to Perl, must be added to the Perlbrew Perl version used by Root AND to the Perlbrew Perl version used by the developer user.

And the last thing, if I try a new Perbrew Perl version... I think that I must add again all modules to the brand new Perl, in both production and developing enviroments...

Is this the correct way????, or I am doing something really weird, making things overcomplicated instead of using Perlbrew to simplify my life?

Regards:
Miguel

Comment: Normally, all the programs tied to a module should have the `#!` line of the Perl you did the installation with.  Then if you run it as a normal program (ie. `./script/myapp_server.pl` instead of `perl script/myapp_server.pl`) it should figure out the correct Perl to run with the correct modules installed.  Unfortunately, Catalyst installation uses `#!/usr/bin/env perl` which is "whatever the first perl in your PATH happens to be" which leaves you where you are now. :-/

Answer (score 3):

I would expect that installing your app's distribution using its installer would place the proper `#!` line in the file.

```
#!/home/ikegami/usr/perlbrew/perls/5.16.1/bin/perl
```

If it doesn't or if you don't use the installer to install your app, you edit in that line yourself, or you can launch the script using that specific Perl

```
/home/ikegami/usr/perlbrew/perls/5.16.1/bin/perl script/myapp_server.pl
```